# How to config scheme in Xcode to always run unit test before archive?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to automatically run unit tests when archiving in Xcode. My goal is to have unit tests run when I click the "archive" menu command and, if those tests succeed, the archive process will follow. If the tests fail, the archive will be aborted.

Answer (score 1):

Select you scheme and go to edit scheme and select "Build".
Check mark Archive for Unit test case target as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for so fast response. I did what you suggested, but nothing happened after I run unit test now. There is no archiving process after unit test unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's just one setting called "Test after build" in Xcode. Someone posted a [blog](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/running-a-unit-test-after-each-build-in-xcode/) about it.